# Why does IE9 on emulation mode render conditional comments?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I am testing css with conditional comments on internet explorer 9 using emulation mode, however it seems to render the css on screen as text. why is this happening?

[image]

```
<!--[if IE]>
  .path2 {
    font-weight:300;
  } 
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because conditional comments are rendered as HTML, not CSS. So if you want styles, you have to add a `style` tag:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .path2 {
      font-weight:300;
    } 
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thank you, can't believe i missed that